# Subwcrev.exe truncates version files

Tags: tortoisesvn

Using (or trying to) use SubWCRev.exe for the first time.

version.txt is a template containing stuff like

```
build=$WCREV$;
```

Whne  "subwcrev c:\myproject\ c:\myproject\shared\version.txt  c:\myproject\shared\version.h"  is run both version.txt & version.h are truncated to zero bytes. Happens every time.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I had also manually added $WCREV$ to version.h by mistake.